# How to run a express.js reverse proxy using grunt

Tags: node.js, express, gruntjs

I used express JS to create a reverse proxy. Basically, it forwards any API request to a python server.

My question is: `how do I run the reverse proxy using grunt`.

Reverse proxy looks like this:

```
   (function(){
    var express = require('express');
    var request = require('request');
    var path = require('path');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    ///////////////////////

    var app = express();
    var path_to_dist = 'path/to/where/static/files/are/kept';
    var TARGET_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/api'; 

    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(forward(/\/api\/(.*)/, TARGET_URL));

    //forward should always be called BEFORE bodyParser, because bodyParser modifies request
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use('/enforce', express.static(path.join(__dirname, path_to_dist)));
    app.enable('trust proxy');

    // var server = app.listen(8080, function () {

    //  var host = server.address().address;
    //  var port = server.address().port;

    //  console.log('Listening on http://%s:%s', host, port);
    // });

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////

    function forward(pattern, host){
      return function(req, res, next){
        if(req.url.match(pattern)){
          var service_path = req.url.match(pattern)[1]
            , service_url = [host, service_path].join('/');
          console.log(req.method.toLowerCase());
          req.pipe(request[req.method.toLowerCase()](service_url)).pipe(res);
        }else{
          next();
        }
      }
    }
})();
```

I'm trying to use grunt-express, but does not work. Takes for ever for grunt to start, and simply crashes after a couple of mins:
Like so:

```
 grunt.initConfig({
  express: {
    custom: {
      options: {
        port: 8080,
        bases: 'www-root',
        server: path.resolve('./express-server/app')
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: hmm... maybe i'm missing something..  why do you need grunt for this?

Comment: I want the server to start up on `grunt` command

Comment: So the question is really: how do you run an express server from grunt

Comment: I ask because it seems rather pointless to run a node app from grunt in this situation.

Comment: When I run grunt, I want to run the express server(which happens to be running a reverse proxy) as well. What alternative are you suggesting? I can run the express server separately each time... but I'm looking to start it all up in grunt

Comment: To use grunt-express in this way, you have to export `app` from your module.